# How do I make my bash script output data correctly?

Tags: command-line, bash, database

I'm struggling with some code I've been writing all day and I'm at a loss, basically, what the code is supposed to do is output a .csv file with all the data in the second to last echo statement, being pulled from `/` . I'm not sure what the problem is but it's not outputting the data correctly and is spamming a bunch of errors about the `du` and `find` command saying that they don't have permission to access various folders.

If I wasn't clear in my question I'll clarify :)

Here's the code:

```
#/bin/bash

cd /
#creates the list file
sudo touch ./home/etudiant/Desktop/main_list.txt
#lists all the files in /
find -maxdepth 1 -type d > ./home/etudiant/Desktop/main_list.txt
#adds one to the number of files in the list
let "list1=$(wc -l /home/etudiant/Desktop/main_list.txt | cut -f1 -d " ") + 1"

#self-explanatory
counter=1

while [ $counter -lt 25 ]
do
    filename1=$(head -n $counter /home/etudiant/Desktop/main_list.txt | tail -n 1)
    #goes to folder 
    cd /$filename1
    #size of folder
    size=$(du $filename1)

    #number of regular files (recursive till the end of time)
    reg_files=$(find -type f | wc -l)
    #number of sub-folders
    sub_folders=$(find -type d | wc -l)
    #number of links
    links=$(find -type l | wc -l)
    #number of executables
    executables=$(find -executable | wc -l)
    echo "${filename1};{size};{reg_files};{sub_folders};{links};{executables}" 2>> /home/etudiant/Desktop/data.csv
    ((counter++))
done
sudo rm /home/etudiant/Desktop/main_list.txt
echo Execution Complete
```

Comment: What do you mean "not outputting data correctly"? What should it output, and what does it actually output? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @muru it's supposed to output the $filename;$size;$reg_files;$sub_folders;$links;$executables

All of these being the number of files found.

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is really *way* more complicated than it needs to be. And you are getting errors (by the way, it is really helpful if you actually show the errors you are getting) because you are running it as a regular user and your user doesn't have read permissions for all the directories under `/`. To avoid these errors, either run the script as root, or redirect the error to `dev/null` by adding `2>/dev/null` after each command (or when calling the script `script.sh 2>/dev/null`).

Here's a simplified version:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in /*/; do
  size=$(du -s "$d" | cut -f1)
  reg_files=$(find "$d" -type f | wc -l )
  sub_folders=$(find "$d" -type d | wc -l)
  links=$(find "$d" -type l | wc -l)
  executables=$(find "$d" -executable | wc -l)
  echo "${d};${size};${reg_files};${sub_folders};${links};${executables}" 
done
```

Some general notes:

- You don't need to `touch` a file before writing to it, just write to it. So you could have done `find -maxdepth 1 -type d > ./home/etudiant/Desktop/main_list.txt` directly, without the `touch`, you just don't need that file in the first place.
- Your echo needs a `$` before each variable you tell it to print. `echo ${foo}{bar}` will echo the value of the variable `foo` and then the string `bar`, you need `echo ${foo}${bar}` to echo the values of both variables.
- As I said above, to avoid the errors, run your script with `sudo`.